# IP SPOOFING concept in Distributed load testing Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, ip, master-slave, spoofing

I am trying to invoke distributed load testing with jmeter (Which have 3 ips in it) and it is running in only one ip. Will other ips also run in the background or they won't even start?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a [Distributed JMeter Test](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) architecture with 1 master and 3 slaves my expectation is that each JMeter slave has its own IP address so you should see requests coming from 3 different IPs to the system under test.

If you need to mimic more IP addresses - there is "Source address" section which lives under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler where you can specify the desired outgoing IP address.

[image]

But be aware that the IP address (or its [alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_aliasing)) must exist on the operating system level in order to be used at this field so you need to ensure that all source IP addresses you're going to use exist and are usable by JMeter.

Check out [Using IP Spoofing to Simulate Requests from Different IP Addresses with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter/) for comprehensive information and example configurations

Comment: But each of my slave machine contains 3 ips and while running test u can able to see only one ip running for 1 slave machine...will other 2 run in background by keeping one ip as a main one?